# add link to admin menu opencart version 3.0.2.0

Tags: opencart-3

**Add link to admin menu opencart version 3.0.2.0**

The opencart older versions than 3.0.2.0 have the ability and also guideline that how we can add link to admin menu for that all versions but into the version 3.0.2.0 they are using the twig files and each and every time i am getting the error for the token generate and also nothing reflected from the twig file.

So my question is that i need help for add link to admin menu of opencart version 3.0.2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add link to the admin menu you must use only `admin/controller/common/column_left.php`. Just check this file and if you coding little bit, you should understand how.